# How to see which R package or function has loaded another R package via namespace

Tags: r, debugging, namespaces

I have a complex R Shiny app (by someone else) to debug and one of the clues is that at some point in its operation it loads an R package via namespace (it happens to be `shinyjs` but that's not material to the question).  I have found and run all the explicit calls to `library()` and `require()` and after running them in a clean session `shinyjs` does *not* show up in `sessionInfo()`.  Whereas if I interrupt the app and run `sessionInfo()` it does show up.  So one of the other packages must have `shinyjs` in its "Suggests" field and then call it explicitly.  To unravel my bug I want to find out which part of the app is doing this, and which functions it is using, and which package it is that suggests `shinyjs`.

There is no explicit use of the string "shinyjs" in the project, so there must be buried in one of the (many) packages the app uses something like `shinyjs::some_function()`.  My question is how to find which package and which function.

So, how (if at all) can I detect, by looking at an R session, which package and function called an R package that resulted in it being loaded via namespace?

Comment: Uninstall `shinjs`, then run until you get an error?

Comment: Thanks @Axeman, I tried that and the problem is that Shiny is unhelpful about exactly where it experienced the problem (there are many files and it is all highly modular).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `tools:package_dependencies` to know what packages you have installed or are using that have `shinyjs` in their dependencies.

```
# Example with all my packages
library(tools)
xx <- package_dependencies(available.packages())
names(xx)[unlist(lapply(xx, function(x) "shinyjs" %in% x))]
 [1] "addinslist"                "AFM"                       "airGRteaching"             "bairt"                    
 [5] "blkbox"                    "colourpicker"              "CRANsearcher"              "ddpcr"                    
 [9] "dextergui"                 "dragulaR"                  "dtwclust"                  "Eagle"                    
[13] "eechidna"                  "elementR"                  "genBart"                   "genogeographer"           
[17] "ggExtra"                   "ggquickeda"                "gimmeTools"                "GMSE"                     
[21] "GWSDAT"                    "lightsout"                 "meltt"                     "memapp"                   
[25] "mrMLM.GUI"                 "npregfast"                 "ProjectionBasedClustering" "projector"                
[29] "regexSelect"               "ShinyImage"                "ShinyItemAnalysis"         "shinyKGode"               
[33] "shinystan"                 "skpr"                      "SpatialEpiApp"             "spectrolab"               
[37] "spotGUI"                   "stmgui"                    "stminsights"               "Umatrix"                  
[41] "wallace"                   "wilson"                    "wppExplorer"               "xROI"                     
[45] "yuimaGUI"
```

Another option to explore where it is running is the `trace` function. `shinyjs` does not have many functions so you can see in which parts of your code some of its functions are being used and how many times it is used.

```
# Example with the function sum
> trace (sum)
> x <- seq (1, 10)
> hist (x)
trace: sum
trace: sum
> y <- sqrt (x)
> lm <- lm (x ~ y)
trace: sum
trace: sum
trace: sum
trace: sum
trace: sum
trace: sum
trace: sum
trace: sum
trace: sum
> untrace (sum)
```

I know that this is not a concrete answer to your question but that way you can get closer to where the package is being used.